# occurrence of character in list type dataframe

Tags: pandas

I need to find the occurrence of "5.1*" string in the blow mentioned dataframe

df

```
0                    [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 5.1*]
1       [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.1*, 11.1*, 9.1*, 5.1*, 3.3*]
2             [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 11.1*, 9.3*, 5.1*]
3              [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 9.1*, 3.2*]

expected result                                               c
    0                    [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 5.1*]    1
    1       [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.1*, 11.1*, 9.1*, 5.1*, 3.3*]    1
    2             [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 11.1*, 9.3*, 5.1*]    1
    3              [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 9.1*, 3.2*]    0
```

i tried using

```
len(df['raw'].str.findall(r'[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]'))
```

but this provides me the length of complete dataframe

Comment: What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'raw']))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are strings use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html), if necessary add word boundaries `r'\b5.1*\b'`:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'raw']))
<class 'str'>

df['c1'] = df['raw'].str.findall(r'5.1*').str.len()
df['c2'] = df['raw'].str.findall(r'\b5.1*\b').str.len()
print (df)
                                              raw  c1  c2
0              [15.1*, 715.1*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 5.1*]   3   1 <-changed first 2 values
1  [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.1*, 11.1*, 9.1*, 5.1*, 3.3*]   1   1
2        [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 11.1*, 9.3*, 5.1*]   1   1
3         [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 9.1*, 3.2*]   0   0
```

If values are lists use list comprehension:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'raw']))
<class 'list'>

df['c'] = df['raw'].apply(lambda x: len([y for y in x if y == '5.1*']))
```

Or:

```
df['c'] = [len([y for y in x if y == '5.1*']) for x in df['raw']]
```

---

```
print (df)
                                              raw  c
0              [15.1*, 715.1*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 5.1*]  1
1  [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.1*, 11.1*, 9.1*, 5.1*, 3.3*]  1
2        [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 11.1*, 9.3*, 5.1*]  1
3         [14.0*, 13.7*, 13.3*, 9.3*, 9.1*, 3.2*]  0
```